# Why does calling close() on an InitialContext break JNDI for all future lookups (Glassfish)?

Tags: java, spring, glassfish, jndi

The second JNDI lookup in the code below fails with an exception when running as a standalone application against Glassfish (which has been configured to expose a `QueueConnectionFactory` and a `DataSource` via JNDI). However, the code works fine when the line `jndiContext.close()` is removed.

In the real code, the call to [`close()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html#close()) is being made by Spring in a [`JndiObjectFactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/jndi/JndiObjectFactoryBean.html), so I can't easily remove it.

Is this a bug in Glassfish, or am I doing something wrong (e.g. misconfiguration or incorrect coding)?

```
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

public class TestInitCtx {
    private final static String QUEUE_CONNECTION_FACTORY_JNDI_NAME = "QCF";
    private final static String DATA_SOURCE_JNDI_NAME = "DS";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Context jndiContext = new InitialContext();
        jndiContext.lookup(QUEUE_CONNECTION_FACTORY_JNDI_NAME);

        // In Glassfish, this line causes the second lookup
        // to throw a com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntimeException
        // (wrapping a NullPointerException)
        jndiContext.close();

        jndiContext = new InitialContext();
        jndiContext.lookup(DATA_SOURCE_JNDI_NAME);          
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JNDI implementation may only support a single static implementation of the InitialContext object.  You can use the documentation at [sun](http://www.j2ee.me/j2se/1.3/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html) to determine how to find out what the actual concrete type of the JNDI context factory is and then find the implementation docs that detail what close does.

Comment: OK, but Spring is calling close() on the context for me. Do I have to forego using Spring if my InitialContext object is one of these static ones?